# Java: what's the difference between Selector.keys() and Selector.selectedKeys()?

Tags: java, selector, nio

Wat's the difference between `Selector.keys()` and `Selector.selectedKeys()`?

Javadoc **keys**()
"*Returns this selector's key set.
The key set is not directly modifiable. A key is removed only after it has been cancelled and its channel has been deregistered. Any attempt to modify the key set will cause an UnsupportedOperationException to be thrown.
The key set is not thread-safe.*"

Javadoc **selectedKeys**()
*Returns this selector's selected-key set.
Keys may be removed from, but not directly added to, the selected-key set. Any attempt to add an object to the key set will cause an UnsupportedOperationException to be thrown.
The selected-key set is not thread-safe.*

Comment: The javadoc of the Selector class explains what these sets are.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a Selector to use it you need to register some keys. These go into the key set. whenever one of these keys is selected then it is added to the selected keys set. The selected keys set will always be a subset of the key set, but may not have all of them.